# IntelliJ 12.0.2 - Elements within Test sources folder are not compiled

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have a Play! 2.0 application opened in IntelliJ 12.0.2 and created with `play idea`command.

Within **test** sources folder, I've created a unit test (using JUnit, nothing special here).

Both ways to run this unit test:

- **From Command-line:** `play test-only MyUnitTest`  => Works well
- **From IntelliJ IDE:** Simply using "Run" button.

Output path compilation of unit test in IntelliJ matches the output path compilation of the command `play test` for tests.

What happened: IntelliJ well behaves when `MyTest.class` has been generated by the `play`command. It just benefit from it as soon as .class file is not removed.

However, I don't want to use `play` command and want to benefit from IDE to run tests.
When I manually remove `MyTest.class` from output compilation path, I expect IntelliJ to recreate it when I launch the test...but nothing happened.

How can I force IntelliJ to compile my unit tests and output them into the corresponding path?

May it be an issue with the most recent IntelliJ EAP version?

Comment: Does it help if you [disable the external make](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png)? Do you have the **Make** option enabled in the Run configuration?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, I had the **Make** option enabled but without its-suboptions checked, does hat matter?  Indeed, when I disable the external build, Scala uses FSC and not SBT instead, and.... that works !! My file is well compiled by IntelliJ. Thus, is there anyway to keep external build and having the same behaviour? Thanks ! :)

Comment: It's most likely a bug with the external build related to Scala that you should report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Ohh ok ! With pleasure I will do it ! Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments is seems to be a bug specific to the [external make](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png) option. If the issue is reproducible with the latest [IDEA 12.0.3 EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP) and latest Scala plug-in, it should be [reported in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL) with the sample project reproducing it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for me when I installed the Play 2.0 IntelliJ plugin.
Once I uninstalled it, my test code was compiling again.